# How to convert the date and time from Now into TXSDate type in Delphi?

Tags: variables, delphi, casting

I have to assign the current date and time to same variables which are of type TSXDate.
How can I do this? RequestDate and RequestTime are of type TXSDate.

```
HEADTYPE1 : HEADTYPE;

headtype1.RequestDate := Now as TXSDate;
headtype1.RequestTime := Time as TXDate;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var
  XSDate: TXSDate;
begin
  XSDate := TXSDate.Create;
  XSDate.AsDate := Now;
  headtype1.RequestDate := XSDate; 
end
```